# Tsql queries into XML using a format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've never used XML before. I have the following queries - that need to be output into XML file in a particular format

```
---- Show Server details   
GO  
SELECT   
@@servername as ServerName,  
@@version as Environment,  
SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'),   
SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName')  

-- Show DB details  
SELECT   
        name AS DBName ,  
        Collation_name as Collation,  
        User_access_Desc as UserAccess,  
        Compatibility_level AS CompatiblityLevel ,  
        state_desc as Status,  
        Recovery_model_desc as RecoveryModel  
FROM    sys.databases  
ORDER BY Name   

-- Sysadmin Roles  
SELECT  
     p.name AS [Name],
     r.type_desc,
     r.is_disabled,
     r.default_database_name  
FROM  
    sys.server_principals r  
INNER JOIN 
    sys.server_role_members m ON r.principal_id = m.role_principal_id  
INNER JOIN 
    sys.server_principals p ON p.principal_id = m.member_principal_id  
WHERE 
    r.type = 'R' and r.name = N'sysadmin'  

-- Find all users associated with a database  
DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE  
(DBName sysname, UserName varchar(max), LoginType sysname, AssociatedRole       varchar(max))--,create_date datetime,modify_date datetime)  

INSERT @DB_USers  
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb  

use [?]  
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,  
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + '' (''+ (select         SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') + '')'' else       prin.name end AS UserName,  
prin.type_desc AS LoginType,  
isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole   
FROM sys.database_principals prin  
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON          prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id  
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and  
prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%'''  

SELECT  
DBName,UserName ,LoginType ,  

STUFF(  
(  
SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), AssociatedRole)  
FROM @DB_USers user2  
WHERE  
user1.DBName=user2.DBName AND user1.UserName=user2.UserName  
FOR XML PATH('')  
)  
,1,1,'') AS Permissions_user  
FROM @DB_USers user1  
GROUP BY  
DBName,UserName ,LoginType --,create_date ,modify_date  
ORDER BY DBName,UserName
```

---

```
--List of all the jobs currently running on server  
SELECT  
     job.job_id,  
     notify_level_email,  
     name,  
     enabled,  
     description,  
     step_name,  
     command,  
     server,  
     database_name  
FROM  
     msdb.dbo.sysjobs job  
INNER JOIN   
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps          
ON  
    job.job_id = steps.job_id  

 -- Show details of extended stored procedures     
 SELECT * FROM master.sys.extended_procedures
```

I don't know where to start

Comment: Im not sure where to start either - you have a lot of queries there. Can I suggest that you edit your post to show just one query. Chances are what you learn from that, you can apply to the rest and if not, then we can help with the next one.... Next, Have a go, your question is more likely to receive the attention if you show us what you have tried.

Comment: You may need to have a look at this first https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107(v=sql.105).aspx , then give it a try and let us know if/where you get stuck